# Fraudulent activity notifications problem from hackerrank

Tags: c++, performance, sorting

There's a problem on hackerrank called [fraudulent activity notifications](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications/problem): given an array of integers and a value *k*, I'm supposed to increment a counter if the median of the numbers up until k , multiplied by 2 is greater than or equal to  the current value being read at k + 1.

So for instance:

given an array: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] and a value k = 3, the median would be 10 + 20 + 30 / 3
= 20.

So we take the value at k + 1 which is 40, and compare: 40 > median * 2? or 40 >= 40?

Since this is true we increment the counter.

---

Now, here's my solution:

```
   float GetMedian( std::vector<int> sample_days )
{
    auto median = 0.0f;
    auto size = sample_days.size();

    if( sample_days.size() % 2 == 0 )
    {
        median = ( sample_days[( size / 2 ) - 1] + sample_days[size / 2] ) / 2.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        median = sample_days[( size - 1 ) / 2];
    }

    return median;
}

int activityNotifications( std::vector<int> expenditure, int d )
{
    auto notices = 0;

    for( auto i = 0; i + d < expenditure.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::vector<int> sample_days = { expenditure.begin() + i, expenditure.begin() + d + i};
        std::sort( sample_days.begin(), sample_days.end() );
        
        auto median = (GetMedian( sample_days ));
        auto current_day = expenditure[d + i];

        if( current_day >= std::floor(median * 2.0f)  )
            ++notices;
    }
    return notices;
}
```

This works for the first few test cases but after that I'm timing out. Any tips on how I can make this go faster?

Supposedly this problem is in the sorting section, I just don't see how I'd use sort to solve this. I'd appreciate any tips or feedback.

Comment: Am I right that in your example `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` is `expenditure` and `k = d`?

Comment: @Green绿色 yes you're right

Comment: So, to compute the median, shouldn't you first sort `expenditures` and then take the middle element or the average of the two middle elements? And then you just need to check `expenditures[d] >= median * 2`, right? As I see it, this algorithm's complexity shouldn't exceed O(n log(n)). Your algorithm's complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: @Green绿色 I have updated the question, this one is correct but still timeout for larger test cases. I think this one is n log n

Comment: Your new implementation looks something like a moving window. I haven't thought deeply about it yet, but I think you can sort the first `d` elements, and when you move the window, there's exactly one element to remove and one element to add. This makes 2x binary search (O(log n)) per iteration, and a total complexity of about O(d log d + n log d). Of course, for this you must retain the original list in its original order.

Comment: @Green绿色 there's a tip saying to use counting sort , still thinking about how to apply it into this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## contract

```
   float GetMedian( std::vector<int> sample_days )
```

This signature is nice enough.
It *looks* like it describes the API
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
We see what caller must present, what will come back,
and the informative `GetMedian` identifier tells us
what math concept is involved.

Oh, wait!
It turns out that caller is required to only pass in an ordered vector.
The code doesn't check for that, fine, it would turn O(1) into O(N) cost,
makes sense.
But there's no comment advising caller that the only way to
correctly call this routine is to offer sorted integers.

When this median library routine winds up in a separate compilation unit,
some maintenance engineer will inevitably call it incorrectly,
and with no error logged will just blindly trust
the returned float as being correct.
Document how to correctly use this helper.

## consistent terms

```
int activityNotifications( std::vector<int> expenditure, int d )
```

Please arrange for agreement between the helper's signature and this signature.

- `std::vector<int> sample_days` (plural, unit of time)
- `std::vector<int> expenditure` (singular, unit of currency)

You probably want `expenditure_days` instead.

The rest of it looks correct.
(Though it does a lot of work.
It has high compute complexity, leading to contest timeouts.)

## algorithm

### pqueue

Expenditures are drawn from some arbitrary, unseen distribution.

Size of the D window can potentially be near a quarter million.
You copy and sort that many integers *every time*,
and since median is a "robust" metric, *most* recorded expenditures
won't move the median value at all.
Yet we copy and sort to obtain same old value, most of the time.
Surely there must be a better way?

There is!

Enter the "heap", or "priority queue".
Create an empty one.
Keep adding expenditures to it, with at most O(log D) cost each time.
Once you're past D days, *also* remove a single "expired" expenditure,
again costing O(log D).

Now you can report median in O(1) constant time, just like your current helper.

### counting sort

Both N and D can be "large" -- 200k.

But expenditures are limited to non-negative real numbers of no more than $200.
Better, they are integer valued.
So the unknown distribution can produce only 201 distinct values.

Do we have enough RAM to allocate 201 slots?
Yes, we do!

- Init the counts array C to zeros.
- Each time expenditure E arrives, note it with `C[E]++`
- Once you're past D days, *also* note that some value X expired, with `C[X]--`
- Compute median in O(201) constant time, that's O(1) time, by scanning C for cumulative sum and ending when you arrive at a sum of D / 2. (Before we're up to D days we end somewhat earlier.)

So complexity is independent of window size,
and only depends on number of distinct values the distribution can give us.

Recall that "median" means "half the sorted values are to its left"
on the number line, and "half of them are to its right".
We found a "left" cumsum of D / 2.
If we kept going past that particular E index value,
the "right" cumsum would *also* be D / 2.
By construction, once we're past D days,
the total value of C will *always* be D.
With each new day we continue to maintain that invariant,
by incrementing a single value and also decrementing a single value.

#### sparse

If the contest server sets D to, say, 100, the counts array C will necessarily be
on the sparse side, with at least a hundred zeros at all times.
We could potentially get fancier with a sparse representation,
maybe an OrderedMap, to exploit the fact that zeros won't alter the cumsum.
For *this* problem's max input parameters, with "small" E's,
it probably isn't a net win,
but for some values it would be.

#### cached index

Given the robust nature of median,
many days the D / 2 index won't change.
It may be helpful to maintain that index,
and manipulate it directly when we increment and when we decrement.
Then we get O(1) time, independent of number of distinct
values in the input distribution (number of C entries).

When debugging an implementation of that optimization,
unit tests should also verify cumsum "the long way" as originally
described above, to ensure that corner cases are properly handled.

#### alternate datastructures

Let N be number of distinct values the distribution can
possibly produce, and M the number that happen to be
currently "resident", currently showing a non-zero value.
We're interested in this case: M < N < D

When using the OrderedMap described above,
we will delete() a node when its count is decremented to zero,
and all accesses have O(log(M)) cost.
Maybe we could obtain O(1) cost?
Switch to HashMap, and run a doubly linked list through the counter nodes.
Defer the increment and decrement operations, noting them in temp variables.
Compute cumsum in O(M) time by traversing the (ordered) linked list.
Along the way, we will encounter the nodes that need {inc, dec},
or we will notice that we skipped over a hole where that node should fit.
So perform such an increment by inserting a counter node with value 1,
and thread it into the doubly linked list.
Similarly, if we traverse our way to the node to be decremented
and it goes to zero, unthread it from the list and deallocate it.
Now we have O(M) processing time for each daily entry,
which for *some* distributions and problem parameter values
will be winning.
For example, rather than bank balances we might be looking at
stock ticker closing prices, and we know ahead of time that
each week's trading tends to be within a narrow restricted band,
so M << N.

Binning might be an attractive approach,
for some distributions.
Suppose expenditures are real numbers,
so N is infinite, or at least close to
[2 ** 53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats).
Divide the $200 range into ten bins of twenty dollars apiece.
Now it's easy to apply the counting trick to the first few
and last few bins, simply to verify that they're not moving the median.
And we have to carefully maintain a pqueue for at least
the bin containing the median, plus maybe a pair of neighboring bins.
When the median shifts out of its current bin we may need to
do an expensive replay of D expenditures to locate its new bin,
which usually but not always will be adjacent.
Frequent bin shifts may also force replays.
The effect of all this is to reduce the value of M,
so we have a conveniently small pqueue that is rapidly traversed.
Of course, an adversary who controls the distribution of expenditures
can always manipulate it to defeat the optimization by putting
all values within a single bin.
For realistic distributions seen by production systems,
the binning approach likely allows significant resource savings,
even when the distribution is not constrained to small set of integers.